# File.WriteAllText the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, exception, text-files, console-application

I am using this code to write to a text file:

```
int num;
StreamWriter writer2;
bool flag = true;
string str = "";
if (flag == File.Exists(this.location))
{
    File.WriteAllText(this.location, string.Empty);
    new FileInfo(this.location).Open(FileMode.Truncate).Close();
    using (writer2 = this.SW = File.AppendText(this.location))
    {
        this.SW.WriteLine("Count=" + this.Count);
        for (num = 0; num < this.Count; num++)
        {
            this.SW.WriteLine(this.Items[num]);
        }
        this.SW.Close();
    }
}
```

but I keep Getting `System.IOException` saying that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process at this code:

```
File.WriteAllText(this.location, string.Empty);
```

However, I check the text file and I find that it was updated.

Comment: You can get rid of `this.SW.Close();` - `using` does that for you.

Comment: No offense, but your code is really scary looking. You should be able to replace all of your writing code and multiple streams by using `File.WriteAllLines` -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: try this- if(flag == File.Exists(this.location){File.Delete(this.Location);}

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace all of your code with the following if `Items` is an enumerable of `string`.

```
if (File.Exists(this.location))
    File.WriteAllLines(this.location, this.Items);
```

If it isn't and you are harnessing `ToString()` from each object in `Items` you can do this:

```
if (File.Exists(this.location))
{
    var textLines = Items.Select(x => x.ToString());
    File.WriteAllLines(this.location, textLines);   
}
```

This should fix your issue with the file being locked because it is only accessing the file one time where your original code is opening it 3 times.

**EDIT**: Just noticed your addition of adding a "Count" line. Here's a cleaner version using a stream.

```
if (File.Exists(this.location))
{
    using (var fileInfo = new FileInfo(this.location)
    {
        using(var writer = fileInfo.CreateText())
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Count=" + Items.Count);
            foreach(var item in Items)
                writer.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```